# Integer Dates in Excel csv to Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

It is known that dates in excel are: "All dates are stored as integers representing the number of days since January 1, 1900, which is stored as number 1, to December 31, 9999 stored as 2958465."

Is there a way to perform this kind of formatting in python using a particular built-in function.

Now what I have the following import data frame
[image]

I want to change it to look something like so

[image]

I used the following code to do this

```
import datetime as dt, pandas as pd

def days_since_jan_1_1900_to_datetime(d):
    return dt.datetime(1900,1,1) + dt.timedelta(days=d)

df1=pd.read_csv('ADS.csv')
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].apply(days_since_jan_1_1900_to_datetime)
df1=df1.set_index('Date')
df1.head()
```

Is there any easier or fewer lines of codes to do so?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quiet similar but you can remove your function

```
df1['Date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df1['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
```

So the full code will look something like so

```
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
df1=pd.read_csv('ADS.csv')
df1['Date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(df1['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
df1=df1.set_index('Date')
df1.head()
```